# Check null parameter in IN Clause

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure with a few parameters. One of them is a `varchar` containing a possible list of IDs (comma separated values i.e. 1, 2, 5, 9). I need the procedure to ignore the parameter when it is `NULL`. This is the way I actually do:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_TEST
@MAIN_ID INT = NULL,
@DETAIL_IDs VARCHAR(2000)
AS 
BEGIN
     SELECT ..... FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON ...
WHERE
     TABLE1.ID = ISNULL(@MAIN_ID, TABLE1.ID) AND
     (
       @DETAIL_IDs IS NULL 
       OR TABLE2.ID IN 
          (SELECT VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT(@DETAIL_IDs,','))
     )

END
```

It seems like the `@DETAIL_IDs IS NULL` part of the code requires a lot of time to execute: What am I doing wrong here?

Even if I remove the `OR` clause and simply add `AND @DETAIL:IDs IS NULL` it takes a long time.

The tables have more than 1 million records each.

Comment: Why not use a table type parameter, out of interest?

Comment: As for the problem, have a read of [catch all queries](https://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) and [kitchen sink queries](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example); I would not be surprised if you are a "victim" of a cached plan based on the assumption of `STRING_SPLIT` returning one row, and thus very few rows need to be returned from your table.

Comment: You wouldn't risk invalid values if you used table parameters. This isn't just about `,,`. What if one of the values is a string with a comma? `STRING_SPLIT` won't be able to handle it. Or contain whitespace? If `TABLE1.ID` is a text field, any leading or trailing whitespace would result in a mismatch

Comment: Hi, i am not using a table parameter since i did not know about it :-) in any case IDs are INT fields and the code behind (c#) will always call the stored with a correct paramater list of int. That said, using a table parameter, how can i skip the IN if parameter is null ?

Comment: `@CHILDRENSIDs` or `@CHILDREN_IDs` or both? Are you looking at the same parameter in all cases?

Comment: CHILDRENSIDs or CHILDREN_IDs .. i corrected the question, was same parameter

Comment: As a simpler fix, you might do a little better to JOIN to the split results instead of `IN()`

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn yes, but the parameter could be null

Comment: For these kind of procedures with an optional CSV parameter i think it's better to create dynamic SQL that skips the whole IN () thing if it's not needed. ORs usually tank your speed either way

Comment: A said above, even if i do not use the IN clause the stored execution is very slow:
     SELECT ..... FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON ...
WHERE
     TABLE1.ID = ISNULL(@MAIN_ID, TABLE1.ID) AND
     NOT @DETAIL_IDs IS NULL